# Private Beta Extension

Tags: discussion

Congrats on making it a week in private beta. Your progress has been great, and we're happy with the general direction of the site so far. We're extending your private beta by a week to to give you a bit more time to get your questions asked in preparation for your opening day!

Keep up the great work!

Comment: Thanks for the kind words.

Comment: Here's hoping tomorrow we get the "Go Live!"

Comment: **UPDATE —** Barring any technical problems, this site is scheduled to go live sometime late Tuesday, 11/6.

Comment: Excellent news - thanks Robert (and the team)... although for a moment, I did wonder why we had to wait until June (doh!)

Comment: Remember boys & girls, [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) - it's the only way to be sure. *8')

Comment: Agree, Mark - a point I make when people add dates to document titles... use ISO 8601 dates, and they will always sort chronologically :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just to complete the loop: Robotics.SE will go public on **Tuesday, 6 November 2012!**

Congratulations!

Comment: Thanks for the update Aarthi, I just wish I'd see this post before I spent time editing [A New Robotics Site Is Soon To Launch!](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/q/2460/3774) over on [Electronics Stack exchange](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/) (since it was originally *Electronics and Robotics*).