# Robotics 10 year anniversary (Remember, remember, the 6th of November!)

Tags: discussion

It's very nearly 10 years since *Robotics* went into public beta, so it's time to reflect on our past and celebrate our achievements.

When [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) decided that most *Robotics* questions just weren't a good fit for their site, many people were disappointed. The idea of a site just for *Robotics* was suggested, but early proposals failed to attract enough interest or activity.

With [Rocketmagnet](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/users/40/rocketmagnet)s April, 2012 [proposal](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/40020/robotics) though, we took our time to define the site, and what we wanted out of it as a nascent community. We didn't rush into the commitment phase, so when the commitment phase did start, in September, we quickly gained traction, and the commitment we needed, resulting in our Private Beta starting on the 23rd October.

After a [successful Private Beta](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/72/37), we were able to go public on the 6th November 2012, and we just kept steadily growing and building our community from there.

After several years, as concerns about the site still being in *Beta* mounted, we tried to [reassure people](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1355/37) that we [weren't going away](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1359/37), and though we missed out on the first round of niche site graduations, our *Beta* badge was finally removed [10 months ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/374096/congratulations-to-the-59-sites-that-just-left-beta).

Over 9 years of the *Beta*, we managed to average almost 2 questions per day, which isn't bad for a relatively niche site. We also averaged around 2,000 visits per day, and attracted almost 23,000 users.

In the future, we hope to grow our community by forging links with other Robotics communities, whether they be academic, industrial, hobbyist or just those with an interest in *Robotics*, and we are looking forward to welcoming all of their contributions.

Finally, I want to thank my fellow moderators, past and present, along with Adam Lear, who was a great help in the early days, and every staff member and community moderator who helped to make our community what it is today.

Utimately though, I want to thank everyone who has taken the time to ask a question, provide an answer, vote, or help make questions and answers better over the last decade. You are the heart of this community and without you all, this community wouldn't be where we are today.

<sub>5th November is Bonfire night in the U.K., when we celebrate the *Gunpowder Plot*, which was Guy Fawkes' attempt to blow up the Houses of Parliament and King James I, in 1605. As such, “*Remember, remember the 5th of November; Gunpowder, Treason and Plot, I see no reason why gunpowder treason should ever be forgot*” is a well known refrain.</sub>